# Why doesn't uninstalling psycopg2 using pip or sudo pip work?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to uninstall psycopg2 in my virtual env.

When I do `'pip uninstall psycopg2'`- I get an exception error:

```
Uninstalling psycopg2-2.9.1:
  Would remove:
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2-2.9.1.dist-info/*
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/*
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcom_err.3.0.dylib
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libpq.5.13.dylib
    /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/.dylibs/libssl.1.1.dylib
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2-2.9.1.dist-info/' -> '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~.ycopg2-2.9.1.dist-info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 87, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 658, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 400, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 289, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 347, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 803, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 718, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 675, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 673, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'RECORD'
```

I have tried doing `'sudo pip uninstall psycopg2'`, but it says no such file or directory exists?? And when I do `'pip list'` it is there? Any ideas how to uninstall it?

Comment: you could nuke the entire `virtualenv` and just reinstall the packages you need...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by doing: "sudo python3 -m pip uninstall psycopg2"

Answer (score 0):

I think u don't have a permission to delete it cause u use a global python environment.

so u should make your own venv and tr

Comment: This is my own vert env, I installed it in the virtual env, not in the global python env

Comment: Ohh wait, I think you may be right. How do I find what is installed in the global python env? Do I do 'pip list' in my desktop directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try →

```
$ export PIP_BINARY=$(which pip); sudo $PIP_BINARY uninstall psycopg2
```

or use full path of `pip` binary manually →

```
$ which pip

# output should be like /opt/anaconda3/bin/pip

$ sudo /opt/anaconda3/bin/pip uninstall psycopg2
```